# Laravel use trans() in jQ added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, multilingual

I wrote a little Laravel web page and I modify often some inputs with jQuery, now I want to implement a multilanguage support. But I dont know how to realize it in jQ.

An example:
I have a unsorted list with n items. If the user click on every item I want to display "No more items available" and in German "Keine weiteren Einträge verfügbar". 
Does somebody have any ideas to realize it?

I using Laravel Blade, the JS content is in a seperated javascript.js file located.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could add the translations in your html page.
Example:

```
<!-- Somewhere in your blade template -->
<script>
    window.translations = {
        noMoreItems: '{{ trans('get.your.translation.here') }}',
        somethingElse: '{{ trans('get.your.other.translation.here') }}',
    };
</script>
```

Then use those from your script. You might want to provide some defaults when using.
Example:

```
// jQuery script 
var translations = {
    noMoreItems: window.translations.noMoreItems || 'My default translation',
    somethingElse: window.translations.somethingElse || 'My default translation',
};
```